# nuxt base component not showing file-loader path on prop binded image

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma

Im using bulma css as the framework.

I have made a custom box component with two props. One for the title and one for the image src.

However when i use this component in another component and enter the src, it doesnt run through the file loader and hash the output. It just makes a path with what i have exactly entered.

BaseBox.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box image is-2by1 is-marginless">
            <div class="is-pos-absolute is-centered-absolute">
                <h1 class="title has-text-white has-text-weight-bold is-size-4-mobile">{{title}}</h1>
                <div class="buttons is-centered">
                    <a class="button button-dark has-text-weight-semibold">MORE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img v-bind:src="imageSrc" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:{
            title: String,
            imageSrc: String
        }
    }
</script>
```

use in component

```
<BaseBox title="Our Products" imageSrc="~/assets/image.jpg"></BaseBox>
```

any help would be much appreciated